# AIX: Parse XML and print element value to console on condition

Tags: bash, awk, sed, xml-parsing, aix

I'm trying to parse a .conf-file that is structured like XML (i know...). Every tag is unique within the xml-file. A sample config could look like this (take notice that an arg can have multiple values separated by comma):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="..."?>
<conf>
    <id>123</id>
    <args>arg1=value1 arg2=value21,value22 arg3=value3 ...</args>
    <someotherstuff>abc</someotherstuff>
    <labels>label1,label2</labels>
    <someotherstuff2>def</someotherstuff2>
</conf>
```

**What I want to do:**

I want to loop over a folder containing all the configurations (non-recursive) and print the value of `<args>` if the `labels` of that file contain `label2`. If the file doesn't contain the label it can be skipped. AIX is the OS used.

**What I've tried:**

There are no XML-Parsers installed nor can they be installed. grep is intstalled but unless I'm gravely mistaken, it is unable to complete this task. Therefore I've been looking up about awk and sed.

```
find . -type f -name "*.conf" -exec sed -n -e '/<args>/,/<\/labels>/d; p' {} +;
```

...is what I found. Ironically, this doesnt return the range from the `args`opening tag to the `labels` closing tag but everything else in the file. Can someone please give me a hint? I'm then planning on simply printing the first (=`args`) and last (=`labels`) line by doing `1p;$p`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using awk to match the args tag and save that line, then the same for the labels line, then match 'label2' and print the args:

```
awk '/<args>/{ARGS=$0;}/<labels>/{LABELS=$0}END{if(LABELS ~ /label2/){print ARGS;}}'
```

Comment: Thank you. Marked as solution for it's simplicity and higher readability compared to Raman Sailopal (its in the nature of the language, i know).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sed -En '/args/h;/labels/{/label2/{g;s/(^.*args>)(.*)(<\/args>$)/\2/p}}'
```

Search for lines with "args" and add to hold  space. Then search for "labels". Where there is a "labels2", copy hold space to pattern space and split the line into three sections and substitute the line for the second part only (the value).